# enabling zoom in controls in google map android using seekbar

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any possibility to fulfill my requirement of enabling the zoom in and zoom out in Google maps in android using the seek-bar? Is there any example that I can refer to?

Comment: get max value of google map zoom level and set it as max value for seek bar. then OnSeekBarChangeListener set the progress value of seek bar as zoom level of map.

Comment: Well, can you provide me a short code? I am unable to get you.

Comment: see my answer !!!!there is an example how to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bar.setMax((int) map.getMaxZoomLevel());
   bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // use progress set map zoom level
                            // update map zoom level here
        }
    });
```